# Merge two Comparator sort

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have the following Classes:

```
public class Orador {
  int id;
  int situacao;
  Expediente expediente;
}

public class Expediente {
  int id;
  int sequencia;
}
```

The attribute "situacao" can be (0, 1 or 2).
The attribute "sequencia" can be (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...).

I want to sort some Orador objects: first by situacao, second by sequencia, but situacao = 1 must be que first one, followed by 0 and than 2.

I was able to do this with 2 Comparator class:

```
public class SequenciaExpedienteComparator implements Comparator<Orador> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Orador o1, Orador o2) {
        return o1.getExpediente().getSequencia().compareTo(o2.getExpediente().getSequencia());
    }
}

public class DiscursoRealizadoComparator implements Comparator<Orador> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Orador o1, Orador o2) {

        Integer situacaoOrador1 = ((Orador) o1).getSituacao().value();
        Integer situacaoOrador2 = ((Orador) o2).getSituacao().value();

        // situacao == 1 must be the first in the list
        if (situacaoOrador1 == 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (situacaoOrador2 == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        return situacaoOrador1.compareTo(situacaoOrador2);
    }
}
```

So I'm calling two sorting methods:

```
Collections.sort(listaOradores, new SequenciaExpedienteComparator());
Collections.sort(listaOradores, new DiscursoRealizadoComparator());
```

This is working as expected, but I want to know if there's a way to do this using only one sorting method, i.e, merge this two comparator into one, in order to optimize the code.

Comment: I am not sure how sorting twice is giving you an expected result? Second sort will discard your first sorting order.

Comment: @tsolakp It works if you sort by the secondary attribute first, because the sort is stable.

Comment: @aseolin What does `getSituacao()` return?

Comment: As I said, it is working as expected, the code sort by "sequencia" first, then by the "situacao". I just want to know if there is some way to do this with only on comparator class

Comment: getSituacao() returns int 0, 1 or 2 (as I said)

Comment: Not in your code.

Comment: @shmosel second sort will still change the order of the first sort even if there are no equal elements. The OP example is not how multi field sort usually works and was king of confusing (as you can see from the answers that assume normal multi field sort).

Comment: @tsolakp Of course it will change the overall order. The point is it won't change the secondary order established by the previous sort. I agree that it's not standard, but it works (and it's kinda clever IMO).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it e.g. like this:

```
final static Comparator<Orador> comparator = new Comparator<Orador> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Orador o1, Orador o2) {
        if (o1.getSituacao() == 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o2.getSituacao() == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        int ret = Integer.compare(o1.getSituacao(), o2.getSituacao());
        if (ret != 0) {
            return ret;
        }
        return Integer.compare(o1.getExpediente().getSequencia(),
                               o2.getExpediente().getSequencia());
    }
}
```

I changed the code to avoid autoboxing (because I hate it ;-)

Comment: It's supposed to sort by situacao first.

Comment: @shmosel Um, no. First `SequenciaExpedienteComparator` is used which compares `sequencia`, then `DiscursoRealizadoComparator` which uses `situacao`. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Oh I get it, thanks. Will change the code accordingly.